# Как удалить повторяющиеся слова в textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, javascript-faq

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
    <button id="butt">OK</button>
    <h1 id="result"></h1>
</body>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

По кнопке, или на евент можешь повесить:

```js
const arr = $('#text').text().split(' ');
const summ = [];

for(let e of arr){
    if(summ.indexOf(e) === -1)summ.push(e);
}

$('#text').text(summ.join(' '));
```